# No duplication for findViewById

Tags: android

I'm starting to learn android and i have question. If i get the field from XML i do:

```
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RatingBar rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1);
        rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                    boolean fromTouch) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.rating_text)).setText("Rating: "+ (int)rating);
            }
        });

        final Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RatingBar rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1);
                rate.setRating(2);
            }
        }
        );
        });
}
```

This working ok, but why i can't make:

```
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    RatingBar rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1); //here!!!

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //remove!!
        rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                    boolean fromTouch) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.rating_text)).setText("Rating: "+ (int)rating);
            }
        });

        final Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //remove!!
                rate.setRating(2);
            }
        }
        );
        });
}
```

or simply function for init instance?
How can i make it?

Comment: OnCreate provides the proper Context handling so that you can use findViewById (a Context function). Before onCreate, there is no context link to your resources.

Comment: Also add @Override to onCreate function,and also use rating_text as class member,because it will not available in onRatingChanged function,see below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the RatingBar to be final but inside onCreate method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test); // also this as noted by other answers
    final RatingBar rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1); //here!!!
    rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromTouch) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.rating_text)).setText("Rating: "+ (int)rating);
        }
    });

    final Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rate.setRating(2);
        }
    }
    );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of Activity `context` is not available in Activity class,its available after `onCreate` Method of activty.

You may define `RatingBar rate` in your class,and initiate in the `onCreate()` method.
Also add  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);` in `onCreate()` method,before using `findViewById` method.

And also use `rating_text` as class member,because  it will not available in `onRatingChanged` function.
So use your code like

```
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private RatingBar rate;
    private  TextView rating_text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1);
        rating_text =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rating_text);
        rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                    boolean fromTouch) {
                rating_text.setText("Rating: "+ (int)rating);
            }
        });

        final Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rate.setRating(2);
            }
        }
        );
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private RatingBar rate; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Where is your setcontentview ???
    rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratebar1);
    rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromTouch) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.rating_text)).setText("Rating: "+ (int)rating);
        }
    });

    final Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button123);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //remove!!
            rate.setRating(2);
        }
    }
    );
    });
```

}

Comment: Copy paste mistake, fixed